Will Nanga Parbat eventually become taller than Mount Everest?
It is a well-known fact that Mount Everest, a Himalayan mountain whose summit stands at an elevation of $8,848.86 \text{ m }(29,031.7\text{ ft})$ above mean sea level, is currently the tallest mountain on Earth. The Himalayas, home to some of the world's highest peaks, have formed due to the collision between the Indo-Australian Plate and the Eurasian Plate, which began around $50$ million years ago and continues today. As a result, the elevation of the mountains is increasing, but at a prolonged rate. Different sections of the Himalayas are rising at different rates. For example, the elevation of the summit of Mt Everest is growing at a net rate of about $4\text{ mm/year}$.
In contrast, Nanga Parbat, a western Himalayan mountain which is the 9th tallest mountain on Earth, standing at $8,126\text{ m }(26,660\text{ ft})$, is growing at about $7\text{ mm/year}$ (almost double of Mt Everest). So, Nanga Parbat is expected to become taller than Mt Everest after about $(8,848.86-8,126)/0.003\approx240,953$ (roughly $250,000$ years). Nanga Parbat may reach $10,000\text{ m}$ AMSL first. Even though the period of $250,000$ years is not so long on a geological time scale, it is still challenging to predict the tallest mountain in future. Of course, there might be some other factors influencing this as well. What do you think of this prediction? Any insights? Thanks!
Edits:
According to a source, the hypothesis states that

The maximum height that a mountain on Earth can reach is the result of a balance between upward growth and erosion. But erosion is in turn influenced by many factors. A hypothesis formulated by many scholars is that the maximum height a mountain on Earth can reach is 15,000 metres.

Learn more:

What's the highest a mountain can grow on Earth?
Why Don't Mountains Grow Forever?

